# Kentico 11 System Generated GUID

Tags: kentico

Using Kentico 11 (Portal engine)
I would like to add a GUID field to one of my pagetypes.  I would like the system to generate the guid (I assume this is done via a macro?). Any idea what macro might do the trick? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is a macro which will generate a new GUID for you.  You'd have to create a [custom macro method](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) to do that for you.  The macro you're using won't work because the document isn't created at the time the macro is accessed. AND it wouldn't be unique either.

Comment: Do you think I could alter the table in SQL management studio without causing severe problems?  

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Guid DEFAULT NEWID() FOR VideoGuid;

Comment: Used the custom macro method route. Thanks.

Comment: You could use straight SQL to add a constraint although it is not supported and could break your upgrade path. If the custom macro method works for you I'd highly recommend it over SQL modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... I just ended up fixing it directly in SQL by adding default value:

```
ALTER TABLE [SomeTableName] ADD CONSTRAINT [ContraintName] DEFAULT NEWID() FOR [ColumName];
```

This is your custom column so you can set the value to whatever your want. I dont see any other use for GUID macro although it is not complicated thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

For others that stumble upon this question in need of an auto-populating unique identifier field, I chose to use existing macro functions to piece together a unique string. This was a more appealing solution than going down the build-your-own macro path.

Here is the macro I used in the *Default value* field:

```cs
{% String.FormatString("{0:yyyyMMddhhmmssfffff}", CurrentDateTime) + Math.GetRandomInt(10000, 99999) #%}
```

Here's an example value:

```
201912200958109206631318
```

No, it's not technically a GUID. It does the job, though.